# How to Modify string Inside character, Javascript Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

How to modify:

```
var a = ' z this is ok z ';
a = a.replace(/z(.*)z/, function(match){ return match.trim().toUpperCase();});
console.log(a); // output: " Z THIS IS OK Z "
```

I expect " ZTHIS IS OKZ ";

the uppercase work, but the trim function is ignored

Comment: in your expected output you have spaces at the very beginning and end, are those supposed to be there?

Comment: yes i just need to remove the space between **Z** and **THIS** then **OK**  and **Z**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are matching the spaces with `(*)`. Change to:

```js
var a = ' z this is ok z ';

// Here, you'll notice that I added the spaces next to the "z" character.
a = a.replace(/z (.*?) z/, " Z$1Z ").toUpperCase();

console.log(a); // output: " ZTHIS IS OKZ "
```

What this does is match everything between the "z", and then rewrites it with "Z" directly next to it.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is also remove spaces in the first and last "ZTHIS IS OKZ"

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the spaces at the beginning and end.